# Inifinite loop forever block mutex in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, blocking

I have two thread: Other thread:

```
while (g_IsThread)
{
    g_SomeMutex.lock();
    Sleep(70);
    g_SomeMutex.unlock();
}
```

And Main thread:

```
while(1)
{
     if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x51) & 1)
     {
         g_SomeMutex.lock();
         g_SomeMutex.unlock();
     }
}
```

If I press Q button then main thread execute g_SomeMutex.lock() command and will wait infinite.
But if I add to other thread Sleep(1):

```
 while (g_IsThread)
{
    g_SomeMutex.lock();
    Sleep(70);
    g_SomeMutex.unlock();
    Sleep(1);
}
```

then it working fine and the main thread does not block after pressing the Q key. I want to understand why it's happening.

Comment: Side note for future readers: Don't manually lock and unlock as is done in this question. It is likely only written this way for demonstration purposes. Instead use a RAII wrapper to handle the locking and unlocking. [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) or [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) will be available on any C++ version that also has `std::mutex`.

Comment: The problem is your main thread basically always owns the lock. It only releases it almost no time. In a real application you don't have all the threads competing for full time ownership the same mutex.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I thought mutexes work like this:
The main thread will lock the mutex and wait until the "other thread" unlocks it, and then continues execution

Comment: @Deebil No it doesn't have to wait when it unlocks.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, where I can to read about it more?

Comment: Not sure, I don't even know what `g_SomeMutex` is. This is just how mutex work in general.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the OS is never relinquishing the "Other Thread" as it always has work to do. Once you add the Sleep you are telling the OS it can schedule other threads. In fact I believe that `Sleep(0)` would do the trick as well.

Comment: No, it did not help ( Sleep(0) )

Comment: Whenever you might want to use `Sleep(0)` to yield, you can instead use the portable [`std::this_thread::yield`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield). But it's rare that it helps.